# Simulate serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am writing a C program in Linux which will read/write to/from a serial port. I know the data that needs to be read and written on the port but I don't have a serial port to currently test this with.

Is there any way to simulate a serial port? Would reading/writing to a file be sufficient? I can have one process write to the file while another process reads that data and writes back other data to the file. Or are there others tools that can be used to simulate a port?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what level you want to simulate the port. Is it just some data going back and forth, or do you have to care about port internals, status etc.?

Comment: Simulating only the data would be sufficient for now.

Comment: IF your PC has a modem you have a Serial Port.  You can also buy USB to serial adapters.  Serial Ports can be tricky depending on the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serial ports on Linux are terminal devices.  A close simulation is to create a *pseudo-terminal* pair; the program that normally talks to the serial port is instead told to open the slave side of the pseudo-terminal, and the simulator writes and reads from the master side.

The `pty(7)` man page has more information.

Comment: Doing this you also get to have another program act as the device at the other end of the serial port.

Answer (score 4):

Despite being an old topic, and my answer is not exactly something the OP was looking for, I decided to share my experience, as someone else might come across it like I did. Instead of straightforward simulation, I used the software called Serial to Ethernet Connector to gain access to the specific device I needed to test the app with. Worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

A character device, even something as simple as normal `stdin` and `stdout` should work if you don't care about attributes specific to port devices.